# iterating lxml web element

Tags: python, lxml

I'm trying to loop within web elements with lxml module but the result is not what I expected.
With the code below, when I read each element of the list in the loop the result is a list of all values instead of the value of each line.

```
from lxml import etree
from io import StringIO

html_content ="<ul><li>...<a href='xxx'></a>...</li><li>...<a href='xxx'></a>...</li><li>...<a href='yyy'></a>...</li><li>...<a href='zzz'></a>...</li></ul>"
    
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree   = etree.parse(StringIO(html_content), parser)

for li in tree.iter("li"):
    url = li.xpath("//a/@href")
    print(url)
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: based on `html_content` in your post - what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You give an absolute xpath and get all the results

```
url = li.xpath("//a/@href")
```

Try :

```
url = li.xpath(".//a/@href")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for the href. The code below is using core python xml lib. (No third party is required)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


html_content ="<ul><li>...<a href='xxx'></a>...</li><li>...<a href='xxx'></a>...</li><li>...<a href='yyy'></a>...</li><li>...<a href='zzz'></a>...</li></ul>"

root = ET.fromstring(html_content)
for a in root.findall('.//a'):
    print(a.attrib.get('href','not_found'))
```

output

```
xxx
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

Comment: Thank you. This may be a solution, but I'm using lxml as it offer more functionality.